# Spring component with method invoked by several threads

Tags: spring, multithreading, singleton

I have the following component which is used by multiple threads since it is being invoked by a listener (Kafka consumer).

```
@Component
public class SampleClass {

private RuleFactory ruleFactory;

public SampleClass(RuleFactory ruleFactory) {
   this.ruleFactory = ruleFactory;
}

void sampleFunction(final SampleObject sampleObject) {
    ruleFactory
            .getRules().stream()
            .filter(ruleFilter -> ruleFilter.getPredicate().test(sampleObject))
            .findFirst()
            .ifPresent(caseWinner -> caseWinner.applyChanges().accept(sampleObject));
    }
}
```

The method doesn't change the state of the class, but is shares another component the `RuleFactory`. Which doesn't have any mutable attributes.

**Is this method thread safe ?** An answer I got, was, it is not since you apply changes to an object which is passed as a parameter. Is this valid?

I can't think of any case other than two threads passing the same object and process it in parallel.

Should this method be synchronized? Is this `final` keyword useless in terms of thread safety?

Answer (score 1):

The method is thread-safe if all of the following are true:

- All of the `ruleFactory` methods called are thread safe, that is, none of them change internal state of `ruleFactory`.
- `ruleFilter` and `caseWinner` are thread-safe
- If another thread has a reference to `sampleObject`, then the state of `sampleObject` must not be modified.

You already said `RuleFactory` is thread safe.

If you modify `sampleObject` in this function and if another thread has reference to `sampleObject`, then there is a race condition. Synchronizing this function will only work if all the other threads are using the method of the same `SampleClass` instance to modify `sampleObject`. You can use `sampleObject` itself, but you have to make sure all other threads that access to `sampleObject` also use synchronize blocks:

```
synchronized(sampleObject) {
   // read or write sampleObject
}
```

Comment: Is `synchronuzed(sampleObject)` creates a different lock for each `sampleObject` passed as an argument? Do I need to have the same block in areas where I read values from the `sampleObject`?

Comment: A synchronized block will lock the instance of the object passed in for the current thread, so other threads cannot go into a synchronized block using the same instance of the object. To be race-free, you have to use synchronized blocks both when reading and writing the `sampleObject`.